# Retaining bands when pansharpening

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, multi-band, pansharpening

I am currently pan-sharpening 8-band multispectral raster satellite images with single band panochromatic images.

I use Arcmap pansharpen raster function to achieve this.

The pansharpened result has 8-bands, even though only 4-bands are used by the pan-sharpen tool. What information is retained in the other 4 bands and is it accurate?

Comment: I'm a little confused. If the pan band covers RGB, why is it black and white? In other words, why can't we simply re-visualise the pan image in RGB at 0.3m, instead of having to sharpen it to a 1m color image?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113899/2856

Answer (score 1):

The [Create Pan-sharpened Raster Dataset tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-pansharpened-raster-dataset.htm) ONLY takes a maximum of four bands (R/G/B/IR) so I think that answers your question.

[How to Pan-sharpen Landsat Imagery](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/blogs/earthmatters/2017/06/13/how-to-pan-sharpen-landsat-imagery/) at the Earth Matters blog is worth reviewing.